# create user in Self sign up API in WSO2 version 6.0

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Under Self Sign-up  API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/use-the-self-sign-up-rest-apis/#/ we are calling /me POST API for creating the user and we are getting response as 201 created and we are not getting response like this

```
{
  "code": "USR-02007",
  "message": "successful user self registration",
  "notificationChannel": "EMAIL"
}
```

what is going wrong here what is causing issue here?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the self-registration REST APIs if you wish to get detailed responses add the following config to the `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file and restart the server. (Responses are enabled based on config in order to support backward compatibility). Anyway, this config should be updated in the REST API docs.

```
[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
enable_detailed_api_response = true
```

If the config is not enabled, there is no response body and the response status code would be 201.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following configuration to the `deployment.toml` to enable more detailed self-registration API responses.

```
[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
enable_detailed_api_response = true
```

Also, note that the existing registration pages do not support these API responses. You need to have a custom UI or improve the existing UI to support the new response model. Before trying this configuration, refer to the following docs, since these improvements were done for a more complex use case.

- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/extended-self-registration-api-and-account-confirmation-api/
- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/multi-channel-self-registration-and-account-confirmation/

I have written several articles on this use case. Following are some of them.

- https://somindagamage.medium.com/user-self-registration-and-account-confirmation-via-mobile-and-email-channels-in-wso2-identity-72ef3210dc41
- https://somindagamage.medium.com/requests-and-responses-of-user-self-registration-rest-apis-in-wso2-identity-server-2b854e3bdb3c